# Spyder Won't Start

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

For some reasons, my Spyder IDE won't start both from the Anaconda Navigator and from clicking on the Spyder itself on the Start menu. It just won't launch anything after displaying the "busy" symbol for a few seconds. Show-console would display the following in the cmd: [image]

I am on Windows 7 and have Spyder 2.3.9.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you a possible fix to this issue: the configuration file located at `C:\Users\310967\.spyder2-py3\spyder.ini` has a duplicate section called `project_explorer`. Find all the duplicates of this section and comment out all of them but one. Then try to tart Spyder again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after copying a huge amount of text into the IPython console, so much so that I had to force close Spyder.

E.g. `[1]:  a = "<huge amount of .. text>"`

To fix I had to find the history.py and delete the `a = "<huge amount of .. text>"` line.

On windows located: `C:/Users/<Username>/.spyder-py3/history.py`